# Можно ли использовать Google API без OAuth 2.0 в MVC 5?

Tags: google-api, oauth2

Можно ли использовать Google API в приложении MVC 5?

Когда проходишь Google аутентификацию, нужно кликнуть на Google кнопку, происходит редирект, и возвращается обратно уже залогиненным?

Ранее я использовал Google API, как указано на сайте Google Developers, но для этого надо было имплементировать OAuth 2.0 аутентификацию в коде, посредством `AuthController`-а и т.д. Там получается объект `UserCredential`, который можно подставлять в вызовы Google API, чтобы с ним можно было работать.

В MVC 5 уже есть встроенный функционал OWIN-Katana, который делает этот процесс аутентификации самостоятельно, но отличается от *Google OAuth 2.0*.

Так, можно ли использовать то, что возвращается после аутентификации MVC 5 проекта для вызова Google API?

Кто в курсе, тот поймёт.

Comment: можно использовать, читайте документацию

Comment: В чем вопрос? Как использовать OWIN-Katana?

Comment: Кто в курсе, тот поймёт. Похоже никто не в курсе, раз задаём такие вопросы. В чем вопрос? В заголовке, если техт осилить сложно.

Comment: можно использовать, читайте документацию - ссылку на документацию как использовать Google API без OAuth 2.0 в MVC 5? Иначе - демагогия.